# Uploading image from android studio to mysql

Tags: android, mysql, laravel

im working in uploading image in mysql database with android studio 
my function in laravel

```
    public function ajouter(Request $req){

        try {
            $produit= new Produit;
            $produit->name= $req->name;
         if($req->file('name')){
           $path = Storage::disk('produits')->putFile('',$req->file('name'));
           $produit->name = $path;
            }
            $produit->description= $req->description;
            $produit->poids= $req->poids;
            $produit->category_id= $req->category_id;
            $produit->user_id= $req->user_id;
            $produit->volume= $req->volume;
          $produit->save();
               return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => $produit
      ]); 

        } catch (Exception $e) {

      return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'data' => 'error'
      ]); 

        }
```

i have tested it with postman and it works. 
i have created an interface in android

```
public interface AjouterProduit {
    String AJOPROD = "http://IP/AnnocesPFE/public/api/";
    @Multipart
    @POST("produits")
    Call<String> getAjoutProd(
            @Part MultipartBody.Part name,
            @Part("description") String description,
            @Part("poids") String poids,
            @Part("volume") String volume,
            @Part("category_id") int category_id,
            @Part("user_id") int user_id

    );

}
```

im blocked how to send all the informations to the database any help ?